# NGINX FASTCGI/PHP - Primary script unknown while reading response header from upstream, client

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have a development box that each user has a www folder in the home dir. NGINX is hosting those dirs from http://IP ADDRESS/USERNAME. And this works great. I want to get PHP working in the same fashion.

/etc/nginx/sites-available-default:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #index index.html index.htm;
        # Make site accessible from http://IP ADDRESS/
        server_name IP ADDRESS;
        #location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
                alias /home/$1/www$2;
                index  index.html index.htm index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/php.fast.conf;
                autoindex on;
        }
```

php.fast.conf file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
#       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/$1/www$2$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

}
```

As you can see I have tried a few variations but seem to continue to receive the following error in the log: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client.

When attempting to render a simple PHP info page The page displays "file not found"

Other info:
Server = ubuntu 14.x
Latest Nginx
Digital Ocean Droplet

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is some kind of errors imho. Your server config looks like:

server {
  location ~ ... {
    location ~ \.php$ {
    }
  }
}
is that right?

Comment: when trying to render

<?php
phpinfo();
?>
I get a "file not found"

Comment: Use named captures. `$1` and `$2` do not travel well. Try something like: `location ~ ^/(?<user>.+?)(?<path>/.*)?$`

Comment: I did change the php.fast.conf to location ~ ^/(?<user>.+?)(?<path>/.*)?$ {
Which seems to render the php ok -- however, I now have an access denied with an existing page that has some JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~* ^/(.+?)/www(/.*|/|)$ {
                root /home;
                index index.php index.html;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

                # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
                # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
                set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* ^/(.+?)(/.*|/|)$ {
                index index.php index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @home;
        }

        location @home {
                rewrite ^/([^/]+?)$ /$1/www/ last;
                rewrite ^/(.+?)(/.*|/)$ /$1/www$2 last;
        }

}
```

The cons of this config, you can't use URI like `/<anything_you_want>/www`.

Maybe it helps. But it's weird, non-optimized and ugly config.

Comment: It is a little odd, Is there a better way to deal with setting up dedicated environments on the same server? Basically, I have few developers working with NODE, PHP and CGI. Each project is a little different. I am definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: @DiscoPanda , It wasn't explained in the question :) I assumed that only php used. I've no any other solution. sry. :( It will be more complicated.